# ASP.NET e C# - Obrigatoriedade de linha em Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, validator

Assim como existe em formulários de sites ASP.Net o RequiredFieldValidator, que obriga o preenchimento de um campo, existe alguma forma de ter obrigatoriamente um gridview com pelo menos uma linha?

Por exemplo, eu tenho no meu site (ASP.Net com C#) uma parte de cadastro de currículos. Como campo obrigatório, tem a formação do usuário, que ele deve preencher com um dos itens do Dropdownlist.

Depois, tem a opção de adicionar os cursos de formação. Cada curso adicionado vai para um GridView. Então eu precisaria ter como obrigatoriedade ter esse gridview pra ele poder cadastrar o currículo. Se não tiver esse gridview presente (com pelo menos uma linha de dado), ele não cadastra o currículo.

Segue o código do Gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gwFormacao" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#E74310" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="curso" HeaderText="Curso" HtmlEncode="False" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="instituicao" HeaderText="Instituição" HtmlEncode="False" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="anoConclusao" HeaderText="Ano/Previsão de conclusão" HtmlEncode="False" />
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Op&#231;&#245;es">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnExcluirFormacao" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/imagens/excluir16.png" ToolTip="Excluir situação" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container,"RowIndex") %>' oncommand="imgBtnExcluirFormacao_Command" />
                                            <ajaxtoolkit:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="cbeExcluirSituacao" runat="server" TargetControlID="imgBtnExcluirFormacao" DisplayModalPopupID="pmeConfirmBox"></ajaxtoolkit:ConfirmButtonExtender>
                                            <ajaxtoolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="pmeConfirmBox" runat="server" TargetControlID="imgBtnExcluirFormacao" PopupControlID="pnlPopUpConfirm" OkControlID="lkbOk" CancelControlID="lkbCancelar"></ajaxtoolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
                                            <asp:Panel ID="pnlPopUpConfirm" runat="server" DefaultButton="lkbOk" CssClass="panel">
                                                <table width="100%">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td colspan="2" align="left"><asp:Label ID="lblTitulo" runat="server" Text="Questão"></asp:Label></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td style="width: 60px" valign="middle" align="left"><asp:Image ID="imgPopUp" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/imagens/confirmacao32.png" /></td>
                                                        <td valign="middle" align="left"><asp:Label ID="lblMensagem" runat="server" Text="Confirma exclusão da formação"></asp:Label></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td colspan="2" align="right">
                                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lkbOk" runat="server" Text="Ok"></asp:LinkButton>
                                                            &nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="lkbCancelar" runat="server" Text="Cancelar"></asp:LinkButton>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </asp:Panel>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="35px" />
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                    </Columns>
                                    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Você pode verificar o número de linhas da grid no ItemDataBound do datagrid. Ou verificar o conteúdo do dataSource do Datagrid.

Comment: @DanielJunior Tem alguma ideia como eu ponho isso em código?